# How to create a sorted vector in r

Tags: r

I have a list of elements in a random order. I want to read each element of this data one at a time and insert into other list in a sorted order. I wonder how to do this in R. I tried the below code.

```
lst=list()
x=c(2,3,1,4,5)
for(i in 1:length(x)) ## for reading the elements from x
 {
    if(lst==NULL)
    {
        lst=x[i]
    }
    else
    {
        lst=x[i]
        print(lst)  
        for(k in 2: length(lst)) ## For sorting the elements in a list
        {

            value = lst[k]
            j=k-1   
            while(j>=1 && lst[j]>value)
            {
                lst[j+1] = lst[j]  
                j= j-1
            }
            lst[j+1] = value
        }
    }

    print(lst)
}
```

But i get the the **Error** :

```
error in if (lst == NULL) { : argument is of length zero.
```

Comment: You don't want to make your life easy and just use `sort`?

Comment: Or use `order` if you need the `index` as well

Comment: I have one more problem here. when i try to use sort by providing column name, it tells me the objects are masked. i tried to unmask them by using attach and with but still my column names are masked. the above question i asked is actually related to this unmasked question. so i thought to make an list of sorted matrix to overcome the problem of masked one.

Comment: "One-at-a-time" is never the way to do things in R.

Comment: @Hashimkhan It is better not to use `attach`, instead try `with`, `within` etc..

Comment: @ akun, i used data[order(colname),] to sort my data, but the mask problem stops me.

Comment: @gregor, so u mean this is not possible in r.

Comment: @Hashimkhan Start on a fresh R console and do it without any attach.

Comment: @Hashimkhan One option is `df[do.call(order, df),]`

Comment: thanks @akrun, ur do.call worked. Please let me know is it sorting the entire row or only one column, can not make out as my data is very large.There are 60000 rows and 200 columns in my data.

Comment: Please let me analyse my sorted data to check whether the row which has been sorted contains the same corresponding column data or there is a miss match. Will shortly update U

Comment: You'll probably need to call `detach` at some point, then never use `attach` again.

Comment: @Hashimkhan no, I mean doing it one-at-time in R is like having a horse pull your car: it works but it's not how it is supposed to work. In R, with vectorization, you can usually do things all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For big datasets with lots of columns, you can use `do.call`

```
df1 <- df[do.call(order, df),]
```

Checking the `order` by specifying the column names,

```
df2 <- df[with(df, order(V1, V2, V3, V4)),]
identical(df1,df2)
#[1] TRUE
```

If you need to `order` in the reverse direction

```
df[do.call(order, c(df,decreasing=TRUE)),]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(letters,10*4,replace=TRUE),ncol=4))
```

Comment: To check identical(df1,df2), it gives and error, i think because of mask problem.

Comment: @Hashimkhan Try it on a fresh R console.

Comment: Your code is working fine, and identical(df1,df2) also goes fine. But when it comes to my data to check identical(df1,df2), it does not find the columnames as they are masked.

Comment: @Hashimkhan It is not clear whether you are running the code on a new R session and without using the `attach` function.

Answer (score 0):

First off, as commenters as pointed, you could use `sort` or `order`. But I believe you are trying to solve an assignment.

Your problem is a typo. Try executing in a console:

```
lst <- list()
lst == NULL
```

The last line evaluates to a null-length vector (`logical(0)`) for which R has no interpretation. Instead you are interested in

```
is.null(lst)
```

which will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: You are right, it return logical(0), but i am not interested in is.null(lst) also.